# Tool to calculate the performance of an application in a html5 android platform

Tags: html

Does anyone know any tool to request the performance of an application in a html5 android platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by performance you are referring to FPS then you can use JavaScript Performance Monitor [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js).

> This class provides a simple info box that will help you monitor your
>   code performance.